# Como llenar un input desde la seleccion de la fila de una tabla en ANGULAR JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

Llevo 3 semanas intentándolo y nada. Necesito llenar los inputs de un formulario a partir de la selección de la fila de una tabla.

Estos datos que están en la tabla vienen de una API que extrae la información de *mysql* y tengo dudas de como seria el controlador. La API para poder llenar esos INPUTS y cómo sería la función de javascript.

Lo que tengo es solo con una función de javascript que me llena los inputs, pero solo con información que está por defecto en las tablas.

Esta es mi tabla en el html, aqui extrae toda la informacion que necesito de la base de datos, la conexion con el controlador es mediante el ng-click="seleccionar(c.cod_aseguradora)" para que me tome el codigo de la fila que selecciono.
[image: Esta es mi tabla en el html, aqui extrae toda la informacion que necesito de la base de datos, la conexion con el controlador es mediante el ng-click="seleccionar(c.cod_aseguradora) para que me tome el codigo de la fila que selecciono"]

Este es mi controlador, y dentro de la funcion paso por parametro el codigo. Con el alert muestro el codigo para verificar que toma el codigo de la fila que seleccione. 
Tambien, fuera de la funcion hago la conexion mediante un GET con la API consulta1.php que es de donde extraigo la informacion para la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la API consulta1, hago el select y la conexion de la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora este es el resultado, solo me sale el alert y me agarra el codigo pero no logro hacer que al seleccionar la fila me pase a los inputs esa respectiva fila
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice este modulo de prueba, la parte de arriba que es Categoria Genero Equipo, esa informacion esta por defecto en el HTML y solo esta con un javascript, al darle click a pasar me muestra todo en los input. La parte de abajo que contiene mas filas esta con la extraccion de la API y asi no me pasa nada a los input, no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi form con los input a donde estoy pasando la informacion, fijate que cada uno tiene un ID y cada ID esta igual escrito a la informacion por defecto del html, si lo escribo diferente deja de funcionar y ya no muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo:  el ID es igual a:                 ROJO Es igual a ROJO

De lo contrario deja de funcionar si no se escribe igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion del javascript, aqui hay un detalle el for que usa la variable pts lo saque de internet y si lo quito me deja de funcionar el codigo, esa variable pts tambien esta en el html que mostre arriba si la quito me daña el paso de la informacion a los inputs.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Añade el código de lo que tengas hecho para que se te pueda responder algo concreto sobre tu propia solución.

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar la publicacion con imagenes de mi codigo explicado

Comment: @EstefaniaRojas, edita nuevamente la pregunta y agrega el código como texto, no como imagen, para que sea más fácil que alguien te responda.